# making div disappear and reappear based on changing form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have several dropdowns that are basically identical.  I want it so that selecting one of the non-blank values will make the `information div` after appear and selecting the blank values will make the `information div` disappear.  The information div should start out invisible.  Here is the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control time_range_dropdown">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
       <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="information" style="display: none;">
    Some information goes here
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control time_range_dropdown">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
       <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="information" style="display: none;">
    Different information goes here
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <select class="form-control time_range_dropdown">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Morning">Morning</option>
       <option value="Afternoon">Afternoon</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="information" style="display: none;">
    Even more different information goes here
</div>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$('.time_range_dropdown').change(function(){
  alert('dropdown is changing');
  $(this).next(".information").show();
});
```

The alert is working so I know it's not a problem with `.change`.  I can't figure out how to make the `information div` appear though.  The code above is not working.  The other problem is that this will cause any change of the dropdown to trigger the `information div` but I only want it triggered if the value changes from blank to non-blank or vice-versa.  How do I do this.

Comment: It's the .information class you want to select on, rather than .ride_information, correct?

Comment: Ah, sorry, use .information.  not .ride_information.  I edited it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `closest()` to select the correct parent and then `next()` to select the respective information.

So, it would be:

```
$('.time_range_dropdown').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    if (value == '')
        $(this).closest('.form-group').next(".information").hide();
    else
        $(this).closest('.form-group').next(".information").show();
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work.  It's not changing the information div at all.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
$(this).next(".ride_information").show();
```

to:

```
$(this).parent().next(".information").toggle(this.value.length);
```

.next() selects the next sibling, however you need to traverse up the DOM (using .parent()) first.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/4q66e2ye/)**

Comment: Good start, but doesn't address the "I only want it triggered if the value changes from blank to non-blank or vice-versa." part of the question.

Comment: @Mic - yup, updated. I was working on a fiddle when I posted the answer.